# Cохранение монет для игры

Tags: python

```
        moneys = str(money)
        moneysave = moneys.split()
        monney = []
        for j in moneysave:
            if j == '0':
                monney.append(' 000 ')
            if j == '1':
                monney.append(' 101 ')
            if j == '2':
                monney.append(' 202 ')
            if j == '3':
                monney.append(' 303 ')
            if j == '4':
                monney.append(' 404 ')
            if j == '5':
                monney.append(' 505 ')
            if j == '6':
                monney.append(' 606 ')
            if j == '7':
                monney.append(' 707 ')
            if j == '8':
                monney.append(' 808 ')
            if j == '9':
                monney.append(' 909 ')    
    
        moneyprint = ' '.join(monney)
        print( 'your save ' , moneyprint)

##На входе у меня 90.## 
##После цикла должно выводить 909 000, а выводит только 909.## 
##Это что то на шифровку похожее. Например если на входе будет 1 то выведет 101, а если 8 то 808 и т.д.##
```

Comment: [Опишите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1309140/edit) проблему подробнее и расставьте запятые, сейчас из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно.

Comment: Четко укажите, какие данные у вас на входе, и что вы хотите получить на выходе. Ознакомьтесь [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: moneys = str(money) - чему равно money? Если money = '9 0', то выводит, как вы и хотите.

Comment: money = 90 (int)

Comment: print(moneysave) ['90']  по идее дальше ни один из ифов не выполнится. '90' не равно всем вариантам. по идее вам нужно циклом идти по moneys по строке сразу и будет норм. #приведёный вами код выводит 'your save  '. заявленую ошибку не удалось воспроизвести.

Comment: Спасибо все работает. Простите что не точно сформулирувал вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Было очень тяжело понять, что именно вам нужно, надеюсь, это оно

```
number = str(input())

answer = 'your save'
for s in number:
    answer += f' {s}0{s}'
print(answer)
```

Пример работы:

```
>> 90
>> your save 909 000
```

Формулируйте, пожалуйста, точнее ваш вопрос или хотя бы указывайте примеры входных и выходных данных